# Block current thread in pthread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I wrote the following code snippet for a small test,

```
i=1;
static void *f1(void *p)
{
    if(cpu_usage()>50)
      {
         //this sleep is not working and thread is not entering this condition eventhough the cpu_usage() returns more than 50
         sleep(5);

      }

    while (i==0) {
        //i=0;
        //cout<<"inside"<<endl;


    } 
    i=0;

    //do work
    i=1;
    printf("i's value has changed to %d.\n", i);

    return NULL;
}
```

and i assigned the function with the thread object,

```
int rc = pthread_create(&pthread1, NULL, f1, NULL);
```

I want to block the current thread, that means suspend its execution. but it seems to me that the sleep is not working. even the cpu_usage() function is not invoking.
but it looks to me that the sleep in f1 is not working. can you guys tell me what is the reason?

Comment: Why do you think the `sleep()` is not working?  Have you timed it?

Comment: because it take same amount of time if i omit sleep(1) or not.

Comment: Kernel scheduling could be an issue.  Put the timing code inside the thread code and get the start and end times printed to `stdout`.

Comment: Hi I tested but the thread is not entering the if block, though cpu_usage() is returning more than 50. It looks like cpu_usage() is not even being called.

Comment: @Pbasak Then it is unrelated to `sleep`. Try to assign return of `cpu_usage()` to variable and then put a breakpoint and check it's value.

Comment: @Basak, Not sure if my question makes sense. but still,  did u print any string inside if (cpu_usage()> 50), just to confirm if it really not getting into if loop ?.

Comment: Is the statement "printf("i's value has changed to %d.\n", i);" printing anything?

Comment: Show us the code in the main function please.

Answer (score 3):

Have you joined your thread from `main`? You have to call `pthread_join` on created thread. Your main thread is probably exits before the thread, created by `pthread_create`. If you are not waiting for it's termination, `sleep` call has no effect.